# Tuckey Filter - https redirect

Tags: java, redirect, https, http-status-code-301, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am trying to do a 301 redirect from http to https.

When I use this rule I get an infinite loop redirecting to `https://localhost/mypage`:

```
<rule>
  <name>https redirect</name>
  <condition name="scheme" operator="notequal">^https$</condition>   
  <from>^/(.*)</from>
  <to type="permanent-redirect" last="true">https://localhost/$1</to>
</rule>
```

And when I use this one the redirection is simply not happening

```
<rule>
  <name>https redirect</name>
  <condition name="scheme" operator="equal">^http$</condition>   
  <from>^/(.*)</from>
  <to type="permanent-redirect" last="true">https://localhost/$1</to>
</rule>
```

From that I am guessing that my writing of the scheme condition is wrong but I cannot find the correct way to write the rule, I tried:

```
<condition name="scheme" operator="equal">^http$</condition> 
<condition name="scheme" operator="equal">http</condition>
```

Any clues on why  this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
<rule>
  <name>https redirect</name>
  <condition name="scheme" operator="equal">http$</condition>   
  <from>^/(.*)</from>
  <to type="permanent-redirect" last="true">https://localhost/$1</to>
</rule>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<rule>
    <name>https redirect</name>
    <condition type="scheme" operator="notequal">https</condition>   
    <from>^/(.*)</from>
    <to type="permanent-redirect" last="true">https://yourdomain.com/$1</to>
</rule>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why the original post doesn't work or what specific issue you solution tackles?

Comment: I tested the above solution with the current version 4.0.3 of Tuckey rewrite filter and it didn't work but this works.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest the following

```
<rule>
    <name>https redirect</name>
    <condition name="scheme" operator="equal">^http$</condition>   
    <from>^/(.*)</from>
    <to type="permanent-redirect" last="true">https://localhost/$1</to>
</rule>
```

I found the above suggestion on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/urlrewrite/9Wy-M17ICpU/K1bEMm4p5-cJ).

However, I am using the Tuckey Filter differently in a java plugin. Here is how I add my rule.

```
    //Add https redirect for example.com
    NormalRule myruleredirect3 = new NormalRule();
    myruleredirect3.setFrom("^/(.*)");
    myruleredirect3.setTo("https://example.com/$1");
    myruleredirect3.setToType("permanent-redirect");

    //Create a Condition for this rule
    Condition myruleredirect3condition = new Condition();
    myruleredirect3condition.setName("scheme");
    myruleredirect3condition.setType("scheme");
    myruleredirect3condition.setValue("^http$");
    myruleredirect3condition.setOperator("equal");
    myruleredirect3.addCondition(myruleredirect3condition);

    //Create a Condition for this rule
    Condition myruleredirect3condition2 = new Condition();
    myruleredirect3condition2.setName("host");
    myruleredirect3condition2.setValue("example.com");
    myruleredirect3condition2.setType("header");
    myruleredirect3condition2.setOperator("equal");
    myruleredirect3.addCondition(myruleredirect3condition2);

    //Register the tuckey rewrite rule
    addRewriteRule(myruleredirect3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

Replace attributes **scheme** with **header** , and i remove attribute **last**.

```
<rule>
  <name>https redirect</name>
  <condition name="header" operator="notequal">^https$</condition>   
  <from>^/(.*)</from>
  <to type="permanent-redirect" >https://localhost/$1</to>
</rule>
```

If the looping problem is still there, maybe you should
take a look at the code level in intercepters/filters handler
you may have conditions to redirect there ! or on server
level rules on domain provider.